# Can you create custom <amp-video> controls?

Tags: video, custom-controls, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I'm using  and would like to create my own player skin and design my own video controls. I see that there are basic amp-video actions (play, pause, mute, unmute, fullscreen) that I can bind to a tap event on my own buttons. Are there custom controls or events to seek/scrub the video or change the volume?

I found the amp-video actions here:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/amp-actions-and-events

Comment: You can try to ask for a feature request on the official [AMPHTML new/issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/click-to-play_overlay_for_amp-video/.

But when your requirements goes beyond this, then the only option is an own player bind via amp-iframe.

By this you are not longer restricted to amp convenctions and may do whatever you need.